# Rules for checking that a filename is safe

Tags: c++, validation, path

Is the following sufficient to check that a path is not malicious, and is the validation against these rules correct:

1. Path must have non-zero length
2. It must not be an absolute path
3. It should not begin with `-`
4. The path must not contain any "path operators", that is `..` and `.`.
5. It should not contain any invisible characters below  . Also, characters that are rejected by Windows API should be disallowed.

Safe/Not malicous here means that the path should not escape current working directory, or screw up the user's directory, regardless of platform.

```cpp
bool validate_filename(std::span<char const> name)
{
    if(std::size(name) == 0)
    { return false; }

    if(name[0] == '/' || name[0] == '\\' || name[0] == '-')
    { return false; }

    auto ptr = std::begin(name);
    auto ptr_saved = ptr;
    while(ptr != std::end(name))
    {
        auto ch_in = *ptr;
        auto check = [ptr, ptr_saved]() {
            auto sv = std::string_view{ptr_saved, ptr};
            return sv == "." || sv == ".." || sv == "";
        };
        ++ptr;
        switch(ch_in)
        {
            case '/':
                if(check()) { return false; }
                ptr_saved = ptr;
                break;
            case '\\':
                if(check()) { return false; }
                ptr_saved = ptr;
                break;
        }
    }

    auto i = std::ranges::find_if(name, [](auto val) {
        return (val >= 0 && val < ' ') || val == '"' || val == '*' || val == ':' || val == '<' || val == '>' || val == '?' || val == '|';
    });

    if(i != std::end(name)) { return false; }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Define "safe" / "not malicious". Is this intended to be Windows-specific?

Comment: "Safe" here means that the path should not escape current working directory, or screw up the user's directory, regardless of platform.